# unable to bind string array in .net 6 due to escaping quotes

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, consul

In Visual Studio, if I set array string in `appsettings.json`, .NET 6 is properly able to map the value.

`appsettings.json`

```
"ORGIDS": [ "1","2","3" ]
```

`Settings.cs`

```
public List<string> ORGIDS
```

But whereas in our development server we are using `consul` key value to set config values. If I set value of `ORGIDS` its escaping quotes like below and .NET is unable to map to a `List<string>` and I'm getting null value.

```
"ORGIDS": [ \"1\",\"2\",\"3\" ]
```

Any solution for this?

Comment: How is consul configuring it? Envvars? Custom configuration class?

Comment: i'm not sure whether we are using envvars, I dont have access to see those details in my server .

Comment: Try this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#optpat